# How to change Data Frame type from object to string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have scoured the internet for this, but all I'm getting are the same suggestions to use "astype" in various different ways. I've tried that, but my data frame for "Main_Genre" keeps returning as an object. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can change this? Thank you in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('blockbusters.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Top Grossing Films')
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Worldwide Gross (in billions)')

df.Main_Genre = df.Main_Genre.astype('str')
df['Main_Genre'] = df.Main_Genre.astype(str)
print(df.dtypes) 


x = df['year']  #xaxis
y = df['worldwide_gross'] #yaxis
c = df['rank_in_year']

img = ax.scatter(x = x, y = y,c=c)
cbar = plt.colorbar(img)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Rank in Year (1 being the best)')

plt.show()
```

Comment: See [Working with Text](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html). Prior to pandas 1.0.0 object is the only way to work with string data maybe using categorical types, but object is the correct dtype.  After pandas 1.0.0 there is a new dattype which is experimental.

Comment: `object` is the expected dtype here. Why do you want a different one?

Comment: I am trying to assign each genre a specific shape for data vis, and I'm finding it difficult to work with objects. But perhaps this isn't necessary

Comment: maybe I am missing something but you could use the `marker` parameter but this may not work under a single plot. I haven't tried it. Alternatively, if it is a single plot this could be pretty easily done using seaborn's [`style`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) parameter: